# Delphi/ios: How to include a dynamic library in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, delphi, dynamic-library

Does someone already successfully deployed an ios App with include a dynamic library? I try to include this library: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC (https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/0d72a13625d8f3e5/GoogleWebRTC-1.1.25331.tar.gz) But its always failed with

> DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC | Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/691B922F-44B9-4780-AC44-6E564866E92A/ALLiveVideoChatClient.app/ALLiveVideoChatClient
>   | Reason: image not found

When I try to deploy the file `./Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC`, then the deployment failed with error `e8000067`. When I change the deployment path with for example `./WebRTC.framework/WebRTC` then deployment work but the app still crash with **image not found**. When I try to load the library using `dlopen` then it's failed also (the application look like frozen, nothing written in the log)

**Note**: on https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC they say the pod contain the **armv7, arm64 and x86_64** slices. I try to deploy on iOS64 or iOS32, same problem.

So as from now (from ios 8) most libraries are dynamic, how to include in an delphi app an iOS dynamic library ?

Comment: Seems like perhaps the Remote Path value should be: ./WebRTC.framework and the Remote Name: WebRTC. Or is that what you have?

Comment: @DaveNottage: it's what I already have :(

Comment: I put the dylib in my projects path and have the deployment manager copy it to ./ on the device. Noticed no problems so far. Your path looks way to convoluted for Delphi to understand. Also is it a 64 or 32 bit dylib?

Comment: @Sherlock70 : what is the name of your dylib? are you sure it's a dynamic lib? maybe I can try with it? also how do you load your dylib? with dlopen ? when i deploy the webrtc in the ./ then the app is named webrtc without any icons and refuse to start

Comment: For OpenSSL libssl.dylib and libcrypto.dylib are needed. At least that was my last information. And I just noticed, they are needed for the simulator only. So...sorry for the misdirection. I'm actually not deploying any dylibs on real devices. :(